# compare array values respectively with real time variable at run time

Tags: c#, visual-studio, for-loop, signal-processing

i'm new to c# programming and please help me with this question

```
 if(x[index] == maxHz)
 {
  //print ok
 }
```

i have program which calculate real-time frequencies from microphone inputs .anyhow maxHz variable is real-time **quickly changing** variable(frequencies).

x[index] array is in inside the for loop. x[index] is array is holding stored values  . i want to check whether the x[index] value is equal to maxHz values. at first maxHz value should equals to 1st value of x[index] array . and then maxHz value should equals to 2nd x[index] value . and then maxHz value should equals to 3rd x[index] value .

like that for loop should pause until x[index] value is equal to maxHz and if it equals then continue iteration . index should not increase without if condition is true.
please someone tell me how to do this task ?

Comment: How does maxHz change ?

Comment: thanx for reply ... that program takes realtime mic input sounds and applied fft algorithm and gives real time frequencies like below.
            for (int f = 0; f < _fftLeft.Length; f++)
            {
                double amplitude = _fftLeft[f];
                if (max < amplitude)
                {
                    max = amplitude;
                    maxHz = (double)f * scaleHz;

                }
               
            }

Comment: Keep in mind that in "normal" code, only one line is executed at a time. You can't simply do `while(x[index] != maxHz) {...}` since you will stay in that loop forever, never changing maxHz again. However, you can use Threads to allow parallel execution, but this is an advanced topic. You can read more here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2):

I think that would simply do the work:

```
for (int index = 0; index < xxx;index++ )
            if (x[index] == maxHz)
            {
                //print ok
            }
```

Change it as your needs. The `length`  etc.

Goodluck.

Comment: yeah you right . but maxHz is changing with time . x[index] length can take as your way. but x[index] and maxHz  still have to do the  matching task untill x[index] value equals to maxHz value before increase index value.